# Индексы в sql-запросе не работают должным образом

Tags: mysql

Приветствую, товарищи.
Имеется sql-запрос

```
SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY `board`.*,
    (
        SELECT `id_board`
        FROM `favorites`
        WHERE `favorites`.`id_board`=`board`.`id`
          AND `id_user`='1'
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `fav`, (
        SELECT `name`
        FROM `cat`
        WHERE `cat`.`id`=`board`.`cat`
    ) AS `cat_name`, (
        SELECT `name` FROM `cat`
        WHERE `cat`.`id`=`board`.`podcat`
    ) AS `podcat_name`
FROM `board`
WHERE `cat`='13'
  AND `activation`='0'
  AND `status`='1'
  AND `top`='0'
  AND `city`='Москва'
ORDER BY `timeupdate` DESC, `id` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Также имеется составной индекс `CREATE INDEX castc ON board(cat, activation, status, top, city);`и ещё один `ALTER TABLE board ADD INDEX`timeupdate`(timeupdate);`
EXPLAIN - http://joxi.ru/Drlpv89S65QlrP

Судя по всему индекс по timeupdate не используется. Как это дело можно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

У вас два индекса: `castc` и `timeupdate`, причем по первому вы выбираете записи, а по второму сортируете. Но `mysql`, к сожалению, в данной ситуации не умеет использовать оба индекса ([пруф](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html))

Отсюда вывод: надо внести столбец `timeupdate` в индекс `castc`, тогда `mysql` сможет использовать его для сортировки.

Можно попытаться задействовать оба индекса, разведя индексы по различным частям плана выполнения, например, так:

```
>> CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeupdate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `timeupdate` (`timeupdate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

>> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
   (1, '123', 1),
   (2, '321', 2),
   (3, '123', 1),
   (4, '123', 3),
   (5, '123', 2);

>> EXPLAIN SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN t3.*
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    ORDER BY timeupdate DESC, id DESC
) AS t1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE name = '123'
) AS t2 USING(id)

INNER JOIN test AS t3
USING(id);
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  |    5 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ref    | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | t1.id |    2 | Using index              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t3         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | t1.id |    1 | NULL                     |
|  3 | DERIVED     | test       | ref    | name          | name        | 153     | const |    4 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | test       | index  | NULL          | timeupdate  | 5       | NULL  |    5 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

Заставить индекс `timeupdate` работать получилось только в том случае, когда выбираются не все данные из строки, а только первичный ключ (на самом деле в этом случае строка даже не читается, т.к. в InnoDB первичный ключ может быть получен сразу из индекса).

Поскольку вас интересуют все столбцы строки, то пришлось `select` с сортировкой оформить подзапросом.

Но в этом случае порядок строк в результирующем наборе будет зависеть от того, в какой последовательности `mysql` будет обрабатывать таблицы. Если первой обработанной таблицей будет наш подзапрос с сортировкой, то в результирующем наборе все строки будут также отсортированы.

Порядок обработки таблиц мы можем гарантировать только указав `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, поэтому указав эту опцию и поместив наш подзапрос первым в выборке мы всегда получим отсортированные по столбцу `timeupdate` строки.

Далее, если фильтровать строки по таблице, из которой мы выбираем данные (точнее будет - по тому же алиасу), то индекс `name` в моем запросе так же перестает работать. Чтобы вернуть его к жизни пришлось фильтр так же поместить в подзапрос.

Т.к. выборка в подзапросах идет только по индексу, то эти подзапросы должны отрабатывать быстро, а с ними и весь запрос. Но реальную картину покажет только тестирование на ваших данных